# Heroku node app hung unexpectedly as verifying deploy

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, deployment

Node app is working all fine in local but showing never ending verify deploy continuously when I do a git push ?

It happened three times and with no success or error message

```
Counting objects: 34, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (32/32), done.
Writing objects: 100% (34/34), 3.04 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 34 (delta 24), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=staging
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        
remote:        npm scripts will see NODE_ENV=production (not 'staging')
remote:        https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#production
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  >=0.10.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version >=0.10.0 via semver.io...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 6.9.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 3.10.8
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote: Verifying deploy......................................................................................................................................
```

error log:

```
2017-01-23T12:33:34.342474+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-01-23T12:33:34.353035+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2017-01-23T12:33:34.343427+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
2017-01-23T12:33:34.431311+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-01-23T12:33:34.433894+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-01-23T13:42:29.700426+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=angular-frontend-stage.herokuapp.com request_id=44ab1149-b2db-436b-b646-f3781dd9df05 fwd="171.61.99.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-01-23T13:42:31.276860+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=angular-frontend-stage.herokuapp.com request_id=070bb388-7a7b-409a-be6c-f7759c1c9ecc fwd="171.61.99.93" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2017-01-23T13:43:24.665641+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2017-01-23T13:43:24.665662+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation timed out: 3600.422883083 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your error logs

`2017-01-23T12:33:34.343427+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start`

your `package.json` file has not any `start` command declared.

> To determine how to start your app, Heroku first looks for a Procfile.
>   If no Procfile exists for a Node.js app, we will attempt to start a
>   default web process via the start script in your package.json.
>   The command in a web process type must bind to the port number
>   specified in the PORT environment variable. If it does not, the dyno
>   will not start.

You should specify it, in order to make Heroku able to start you app:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "start": "node server.js"
  ...
}
```

## UPDATE #1:

Try to remove the `Procfile`, then in the `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node server/app.js",
  "postinstall": "bower install && ./bin/www staging"
}
```

Heroku will run `npm install` that will execute the `bower install` present in the [postinstall](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) command.

Moreover you can read ["Heroku: Customizing The Build Process"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process)

Comment: Have added the procfile with 
web: npm install
web: node server/app.js

Comment: Really strange, reading the log file the error occurs at the same. Did you try with: `node ./server/app.js`

Comment: in local everything is working fine and in packagejson it is  "scripts": {
    "install": "bower install",
    "postinstall": "./bin/www staging"
  }